# How to close application shortcut in android?

Tags: android

Hi i am creating application shortcut to my application. My application shortcut is in the front of home screen. When i close the application at that time how to close/delete application shortcut. I need source code. Please any one help me. Thanks.

Code is here. Help me.

```
Intent shortcutintent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(
    getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.icon);
shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, 
    new Intent(getApplicationContext() , FirstScreenActivity.class));
sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);
```

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall shortcut you can use Intent with `"com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"` action. You should have `"com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"` permission in the manifest also.

```
Intent uninstallShortcutIntent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
uninstallShortcutIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
uninstallShortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
uninstallShortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, 
    new Intent(getApplicationContext() , FirstScreenActivity.class));
sendBroadcast(uninstallShortcutIntent);
```

I haven't test it. Get it from the launcher sources: [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_launcher/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) and [UninstallShortcutReceiver](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_launcher/blob/master/src/com/android/launcher/UninstallShortcutReceiver.java)
Note: AFAIK, it may not work in some third-party launchers, it is not part of Android SDK.

Comment: Thanks. But the icon is display into the home screen.